# Excel Pivot Table - Calculated field returning "1" for all rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, pivot-table

Column C (**Final Contracts**) in My Pivot Table is a count of "*Leads.LeadID*" in My Data per **User Name**. Column I (**Test**) in My Pivot Table is a calculated field with the formula `=count(Leads.LeadID)`. This is the same logic used to return Final Contracts. Values in **Test** should be identical to values in **Final Contracts**.

But, as you can see in My Pivot Table, the return value for every row in **Test** is "1".

I need to understand what I am doing wrong with my calculated field so I can create more complex logic, i.e.) average of calls / count of final contracts.

My Pivot Table:
[image: My Pivot Table]

My Data:
[image: My Data]

Comment: If you want more complex logic in your measures, you should begin with Power Pivot. Going down the route of calculated fields is going to hit a dead end very quickly. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/get-started-with-power-pivot-in-microsoft-excel-fdfcf944-7876-424a-8437-1a6c1043a80b

Comment: @FlexYourData, thank you